# Chrome OS Developer Tools Disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-os

On my school chromebook developer tools just got disabled or something.

When i right click to inspect an element, the "inspect" button is grayed out and if i click the options button in the top right, go down to more tools the developer tools button is grayed out there too.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening and why it is happening?

(Developer mode is enabled on my chromebook)

Comment: Can you please clarify if the "school chromebook" is administered by the school or is it your personal machine that you are just using for school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Chromebook, Chrome Developer Tools is enabled/disabled through Chrome Policies, which is maintained by the Chrome Management Console as part of a Google Work account. In this case, the policy is [DeveloperToolsDisabled](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DeveloperToolsDisabled).

In Windows, it is possible to enable/disable it in the registry, and there is possibly a Preferences file in OSX.

I'm afraid you would need to speak to your school's IT department about this, as they are the only ones with access to these policies.